# SQL procedure executes first line then stops

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running an SQL procedure that has to update a certain table. When I run the procedure it says successfully completed, yet the records are not updated when I try to debug it, it run only the line `SET ANSI ON`, then it gives the successful message. I am using SQL server 2012

Am I missing something, is there anything I need to add? See my code here:

```
USE [CADDe_ProdCopy]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_sms_X203]    Script Date: 2015/09/03 08:28:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




ALTER        procedure [dbo].[sp_sms_X203]
as
    declare @lCount int
    set @lCount = (select count(*) from tbl_X203_SMS where SMSSent = 0 )
    if @lCount > 0 
        begin
        DECLARE @cSMSeMail varchar(100)
        declare @cSMSType varchar(10)
        declare @cSMSSent int
        declare @cRA varchar(10)
        declare @cWizard varchar(7)
        declare @cCName varchar(26)
        declare @cContact varchar(30)
        declare @cUsed_KM int
        declare @cAmount_Due decimal(18, 2)
        declare @cSMSMessage varchar(160)
        declare @cvblf varchar(1)
        declare @cCheckInDt datetime
        declare @cCheckOutDt datetime
        declare @err int


    set @cvblf = '|'
    declare lcursor CURSOR FOR 
        Select SMSType, RA, CName, Contact, Used_KM, Amount_Due, eMail, [CheckInDateTime] ,[CheckOutDateTime] 
        From tbl_X203_SMS WHERE SMSSent = 0
    open lcursor
    fetch next from lcursor into @cSMSType, @cRA, @cCName, @cContact, @cUsed_KM, @cAmount_Due, @cSMSeMail, @cCheckInDt, @cCheckOutDt
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
        --SET @cContact = '+27834115771'
        --SET @cSMSeMail = 'amangelsdorf@avis.co.za'


-- Check that the date of the checkin is within same day
            if rtrim(ltrim(@cSMSType)) = 'CheckIn'
                begin               
                    if datediff(day,@cCheckInDt,getdate()) = 0
                    begin
                        SET @cSMSMessage = left('Thank you '+ @cCName +' for renting with AVIS.',160)
                        SET @cSMSMessage = left( @cSMSMessage + ' RA#' + @cRA + 'Retrieve your invoice at http://www.avis.co.za/inv' ,160)
                        --if @cAmount_Due > 0
                        --  SET @cSMSMessage = left( @cSMSMessage + @cvbLf + 'AMT:R ' + cast(@cAmount_Due as varchar),160)
                        exec sp_sms_xml_post @cContact, @cSMSMessage, @cSMSeMail
                    end
                end


    -- Check that the date of the checkout is within same day
            if rtrim(ltrim(@cSMSType)) = 'CheckOut'
                begin
                if datediff(day,@cCheckOutDt,getdate()) = 0
                    begin
                        --SET @cSMSMessage = left( 'Thank you for choosing AVIS.' + @cvbLf + 'For any  assistance contact the AVIS Careline on Tel: 0800001669' ,160)
                        SET @cSMSMessage = left( 'Thank you for choosing AVIS. ' + @cvbLf + 'Kindly contact 0800001669 for any roadside or emergency assistance.' ,160)
                        exec sp_sms_xml_post @cContact, @cSMSMessage, @cSMSeMail
                    end
                end

            set @err = @@error
            if @err = 0
                begin
                    --print 'no error'  
                    update tbl_X203_SMS set SMSSent = 1 where SMSType = @cSMSType and RA = @cRA                     
                end
            fetch next from lcursor into @cSMSType, @cRA, @cCName, @cContact, @cUsed_KM, @cAmount_Due, @cSMSeMail, @cCheckInDt, @cCheckOutDt
        end

    close lcursor
    deallocate lcursor
end
```

`

Comment: So this is the code to create / alter your stored procedure and won't execute  it. For that you need to use exec [dbo].[sp_sms_X203]

Comment: @SteveFord thanks a lot, I was a bit careless I think, I have now created a job using your suggestion and it works like a charm, by the way how do I then get to mark your comments as answer :)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer and you can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have shown is the code to create / alter a stored procedure and won't execute it, hence the Successfully Compiled response.

In order to execute this procedure you will need to use the `exec` statement:

```
exec [dbo].[sp_sms_X203]
```

Answer (score 1):

You check your count value in
 set @lCount = (select count(*) from tbl_X203_SMS where SMSSent = 0 )
    if @lCount > 0

because may be you are getting value as 0 so it is not going inside the if condition, you can use print(@lCount ) before if and execute stored procedure from sql server.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my main problem is, then debugging the stored prod it does not even get to the count part, it only executes the first 3 lines then stops with message "Command(s) completed successfully "

Comment: ya, debugging is bit difficult in sql server